# how do I align these items and a sidebar to look like this?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

im trying to align some items in css to look like this, preferably with flexbox. Thank you.

```
| Text   A | text   B | text   C | video |
| text   d | text   E | text   F | video |
```

the video is the same video in both rows, trying to get it to extend along the side as a sidebar

```css
.services {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1 1 500px;
}

.serviceclasses {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<section id="s2">
  <h2>What do we do here?</h2>
  <br>
  <div id="list">
    <div class="services">
      <div><a href="" id="item1" class="serviceclasses">1</a></div>
      <div><a href="" id="item2" class="serviceclasses">2</a></div>
      <div><a href="" id="item3" class="serviceclasses">3</a></div>
      <div><a href="" id="item4" class="serviceclasses">4</a></div>
      <div><a href="" id="item5" class="serviceclasses">5</a></div>
      <div><a href="" id="item6" class="serviceclasses">6</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="side">
      <aside class="video-sidebar">
        <figure>
          <figcaption>VIDEO</figcaption>
          <div class="video">
            <video controls>
              <source src = "felixynwa.mp4" width="20px" height="20px">
            </video>
          </div>
          <figcaption>VIDEO BOTTOM TEXT</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </aside>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to alter your current HTML:

```css
#list {
  display: flex;
}

.services {
  display: grid;
  /* 2 rows of same height, 3 columns of same width */
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

Try it:

```css
#list {
  display: flex;
}

.services {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / repeat(3, 1fr);
}


/* Demo only */

#list, .services {
  gap: 1em;
}

.services div, .side {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.services a {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="services">
    <div><a href="">1</a></div>
    <div><a href="">2</a></div>
    <div><a href="">3</a></div>
    <div><a href="">4</a></div>
    <div><a href="">5</a></div>
    <div><a href="">6</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <aside>
      <figure>
        <figcaption>VIDEO</figcaption>
        <div class="video">
          <video controls>
              <source width="20px" height="20px">
            </video>
        </div>
        <figcaption>VIDEO BOTTOM TEXT</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

...or, with `display: contents`:

```css
#list {
  display: grid;
  /* 2 rows of same height, 3 columns of same width plus 1 of auto width */
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / repeat(3, 1fr) auto;
}
#list {
  display: grid;
}
.services {
  /* Ignore the element itself, as if its children were #list's direct children */
  display: contents;
}

.side {
  /* Spans all rows, starts and ends at the last column */
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: -2; /* -2 means second last vertical grid line */
}
```

Try it:

```css
#list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr 1fr / repeat(3, 1fr) auto;
}

.services {
  display: contents;
}

.side {
  grid-row: 1 / -1;
  grid-column: -2;
}


/* Demo only */

#list {
  gap: 1em;
}

.services div, .side {
  outline: 2px solid black;
}

.services a {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="services">
    <div><a href="">1</a></div>
    <div><a href="">2</a></div>
    <div><a href="">3</a></div>
    <div><a href="">4</a></div>
    <div><a href="">5</a></div>
    <div><a href="">6</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="side">
    <aside>
      <figure>
        <figcaption>VIDEO</figcaption>
        <div class="video">
          <video controls>
              <source width="20px" height="20px">
            </video>
        </div>
        <figcaption>VIDEO BOTTOM TEXT</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`grid-template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template)
- [`display: contents`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#box)
- [`grid-row`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) and [`grid-column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column)